# INSERT on duplicate key Vs Truncate and Insert - updating all records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table with about 200-400 records of traffic related data

id, name, segment, avg_speed, time

I get the data from an XML file. When the XML changes I then update my new data to the database. The ID, name and segment don't change while the avg_speed and time do. Usually, about 95% of the avg_speed and time change when I need to update the table. So let's consider that I need to update the entire table records.

Which is the better way?

1  `INSERT on duplicate key UPDATE` ... only the avg_speed and time column

or

2  `TRUNCATE table` -> then INSERT all records.

I'm currently using the second but will appreciate any input!

Also (not really related to the title), since I need to update the entire table it does not make sense to put a timestamp for each record. Is it ok to create a different table and store a timestamp for the update of the traffic table with only one record that gets update everytime there's new data?

Comment: Your both cases numbered as 1, so answer is first 1.

Comment: @Hamlet Weird, I had a 2. in the edit window but a 1. in the preview. Thanks!

Comment: Option 2 might be faster, but it can't be used in a transaction. Another thread might end up with an empty table (I don't know if that would be a problem for you...). It's probably not worth trying to optimize for 400 rows.